# SQL, Incorrect syntax on CASE statement near the keyword 'FROM'

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, syntax, case

I am trying to get the below code to work, individually the two pieces of code (in the `WHEN` part and the `ELSE` part) work but when used in this `CASE` statement I get an error

> "Incorrect syntax near 'CAST', expected 'AS'." error.

Basically if the `WHEN` statements code is equals to or greater than 24 then use the `THEN` statement if its is under 24 then use the `ELSE` statement.

I cannot seem to get this to work after trying for several hours any indication as to where I am going wrong would be greatly appreciated.

```
SELECT CASE 
        WHEN 
            (convert(float,datediff(mi, start_work, end_work))/60) >= '24'
        THEN
            (convert(float,datediff(mi, start_work, end_work))/60)
        ELSE
            (CAST(convert(varchar(2), dateadd(minute, datediff(minute, start_time, end_time), 0), 114) 
            * 60 + RIGHT (convert(varchar(5), dateadd(minute, datediff(minute, start_time, end_time), 0), 114),
            CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(':',convert(varchar(5), dateadd(minute, datediff(minute, start_time, end_time), 0), 114)) > 0
            THEN LEN(convert(varchar(5), dateadd(minute, datediff(minute, start_time, end_time), 0), 114))-3
            ELSE LEN(convert(varchar(5), dateadd(minute, datediff(minute, start_time, end_time), 0), 114))
            END) AS decimal) / 60
FROM  NDB.dbo.statusa 
INNER JOIN NDB.dbo.details ON statusa.vkey = details.vkey
INNER JOIN NDB.dbo.chegu ON statusa.ckey = NDB.dbo.chegu.gkey
WHERE start_time!= end_time AND string1 = Visit_Id and NDB.dbo.chegu.name = 'loft'
     AS [Working]
```

Comment: (convert(float,datediff(mi, start_work, end_work))/60) >= '24' should not have quotes around 24.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you need to close your `case` statement

```
 case when ... then ... else ... end
```

Answer (score 10):

There should be an `END` before the `FROM` clause and you should also remove`(` before `CAST`.

Answer (score 5):

There arent closing parenthesis.

```
SELECT CASE 
    WHEN 
        (convert(float,datediff(mi, start_work, end_work))/60) >= '24'
    THEN
        (convert(float,datediff(mi, start_work, end_work))/60)
    ELSE
        (CAST(convert(varchar(2), dateadd(minute, datediff(minute, start_time, end_time), 0), 114) 
        * 60 + RIGHT (convert(varchar(5), dateadd(minute, datediff(minute, start_time, end_time), 0), 114),
        CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(':',convert(varchar(5), dateadd(minute, datediff(minute, start_time, end_time), 0), 114)) > 0
        THEN LEN(convert(varchar(5), dateadd(minute, datediff(minute, start_time, end_time), 0), 114))-3
        ELSE LEN(convert(varchar(5), dateadd(minute, datediff(minute, start_time, end_time), 0), 114))
        END) AS decimal) / 60)
```

Answer (score 5):

Unclosed parentheses and a case statement needed an END.

```
SELECT CASE 
            WHEN (convert(FLOAT, datediff(mi, start_work, end_work)) / 60) >= '24'
                THEN (convert(FLOAT, datediff(mi, start_work, end_work)) / 60)
            ELSE CAST(convert(VARCHAR(2), dateadd(minute, datediff(minute, start_time, end_time), 0), 114) * 60 
                 + RIGHT(
                        convert(VARCHAR(5), dateadd(minute, datediff(minute, start_time, end_time), 0), 114), 
                        CASE 
                            WHEN CHARINDEX(':', convert(VARCHAR(5), dateadd(minute, datediff(minute, start_time, end_time), 0), 114)) > 0
                                THEN LEN(convert(VARCHAR(5), dateadd(minute, datediff(minute, start_time, end_time), 0), 114)) - 3
                            ELSE LEN(convert(VARCHAR(5), dateadd(minute, datediff(minute, start_time, end_time), 0), 114))
                        END
                        ) AS DECIMAL) / 60
        END

FROM NDB.dbo.statusa
INNER JOIN NDB.dbo.details
    ON statusa.vkey = details.vkey
INNER JOIN NDB.dbo.chegu
    ON statusa.ckey = NDB.dbo.chegu.gkey
WHERE start_time != end_time
    AND string1 = Visit_Id
    AND NDB.dbo.chegu.NAME = 'loft' AS [Working]
```

Answer (score 5):

I realized this answer is too late for the reward. But your script is WAY too long. This will do exactly the same as you are trying to achieve, fixing the error in your code, is just patching bad code:

```
SELECT 
  datediff(mi, 0, end_time - start_time)/60.0%24
FROM  
 ....
```

Answer (score 4):

Two basic formulations for CASE expression 
1) Simple CASE expressions 
A simple CASE expression checks one expression against multiple values. Within a SELECT statement, a simple CASE expression allows only an equality check; no other comparisons are made. A simple CASE expression operates by comparing the first expression to the expression in each WHEN clause for equivalence. If these expressions are equivalent, the expression in the THEN clause will be returned.

2) Searched CASE expressions
A searched CASE expression allows comparison operators, and the use of AND and/or OR between each Boolean expression. The simple CASE expression checks only for equivalent values and can not contain Boolean expressions. The basic syntax for a searched CASE expression is shown below:

Read more here: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/04/14/sql-server-case-statementexpression-examples-and-explanation/

Answer (score 4):

There are 2 errors in the code.
**First**, you have an extra parenthesis in front of CAST which is not needed (and isn't closed ever).  Change

```
(CAST(convert(varchar(2), dateadd(minute, datediff(minute, start_time, end_time), 0), 114)
```

to

```
CAST(convert(varchar(2), dateadd(minute, datediff(minute, start_time, end_time), 0), 114)
```

**Second:** Add END at the close of the CASE statement before the FROM keyword (as @gefei points out above as well) . Your final code should look like the following:

```
SELECT CASE 
        WHEN 
            (convert(float,datediff(mi, start_work, end_work))/60) >= '24'
        THEN
            (convert(float,datediff(mi, start_work, end_work))/60)
        ELSE
            CAST(convert(varchar(2), dateadd(minute, datediff(minute, start_time, end_time), 0), 114) 
            * 60 + RIGHT (convert(varchar(5), dateadd(minute, datediff(minute, start_time, end_time), 0), 114),
            CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(':',convert(varchar(5), dateadd(minute, datediff(minute, start_time, end_time), 0), 114)) > 0
            THEN LEN(convert(varchar(5), dateadd(minute, datediff(minute, start_time, end_time), 0), 114))-3
            ELSE LEN(convert(varchar(5), dateadd(minute, datediff(minute, start_time, end_time), 0), 114))
            END) AS decimal) / 60
        END
FROM  NDB.dbo.statusa 
INNER JOIN NDB.dbo.details ON statusa.vkey = details.vkey
INNER JOIN NDB.dbo.chegu ON statusa.ckey = NDB.dbo.chegu.gkey
WHERE start_time!= end_time AND string1 = Visit_Id and NDB.dbo.chegu.name = 'loft'
     AS [Working]
```

Answer (score 2):

The RIGHT() function does not have a second parameter

```
RIGHT (convert(varchar(5), dateadd(minute, datediff(minute, start_time, end_time), 0), 114),
```

or: you missed the ending parenthesis behind AS decimal

```
END ) AS decimal ) ) / 60
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's the corrected version of your code:

```
SELECT CASE 
        WHEN 
            (convert(float,datediff(mi, start_work, end_work))/60) >= '24'
        THEN
            (convert(float,datediff(mi, start_work, end_work))/60)
        ELSE
            (CAST(convert(varchar(2), dateadd(minute, datediff(minute, start_time, end_time), 0), 114) 
            * 60 + RIGHT (convert(varchar(5), dateadd(minute, datediff(minute, start_time, end_time), 0), 114),
            CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(':',convert(varchar(5), dateadd(minute, datediff(minute, start_time, end_time), 0), 114)) > 0
            THEN LEN(convert(varchar(5), dateadd(minute, datediff(minute, start_time, end_time), 0), 114))-3
            ELSE LEN(convert(varchar(5), dateadd(minute, datediff(minute, start_time, end_time), 0), 114))
            END) AS decimal) / 60 
        END
AS [Working]
FROM  NDB.dbo.statusa  INNER JOIN NDB.dbo.details ON statusa.vkey = details.vkey INNER JOIN NDB.dbo.chegu ON statusa.ckey = NDB.dbo.chegu.gkey WHERE start_time!= end_time AND string1 = Visit_Id and NDB.dbo.chegu.name = 'loft'
```

Basically, you had a missing END in the outer SELECT..CASE statement and the selected column alias [Working] was mistakenly put at the end of the query rather than in the select clause of the query.